# Using Java's Regex to extract a word from a path name

Tags: java, regex

I have a directory like this and I am trying to extract the word "photon" from just before "photon.exe".

C:\workspace\photon\output\i686\diagnostic\photon.exe(Suspended) Thread(Running)

My code looks like this:

```
String path = "C:\workspace\photon\output\i686\diagnostic\photon.exe(Suspended) Thread(Running)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".+\\\\(.+).exe");

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(path);

System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
```

No matter what permutations I try I keep getting IllegalStateExceptions etc, despite this regular expression working on http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/index.html.

Thanks in advance for any help.  I am super frustrated at this point >.<

Comment: Why not split the string at the slashes and get the last item?  http://www.java-examples.com/java-string-split-example

Comment: As an aside your `.` should be escaped (`\\.`) since it will currently match any character.  e.g. it would parse "c" out of `C:\blah\chexes\photon.exe`.

Comment: By that I meant the last `.`; the first two are actually meant to be a wildcard and are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the following regular expression: `^.*\\(.*)\.exe.*$` and the file name will be in the first match group. Here is an [example](http://rubular.com/r/Tlu9jkibdy).

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        final String input = args[0];
        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^.*\\\\(.*)\\.exe.*$");
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
        if (matcher.find())
        {
            System.out.println("matcher.group(1) = " + matcher.group(1));
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.format("%s does not match %s\n", input, pattern.pattern());
        }
    }
}
```

run it with `C:\workspace\photon\output\i686\diagnostic\photon.exe(Suspended) Thread(Running)` as the input and here is the expected output:

```
matcher.group(1) = photon
```

Comment: A very complete example! Thank you very much :)

Comment: Four backaslashes? I would move to another planet first.

Comment: tchrist: you have to escape the \ in the regex in every language because it is the escape character itself, and you have to escape the \ in Java Strings because like almost every other language it is used as the escape character as well. In a perfect world there would be an escape character that was only used for escaping.

Answer (score 7):

You need to actually run the matcher:

```
if ( matcher.find() ) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Note that I use `matcher.find()` above instead of `matcher.matches()` because your regex is not set up to match the entire string (it won't match the `(Suspended...` part).  Since that's the case, you don't really need the preamble to the slash; `\\\\(.+).exe` should work fine.

Of course, this is mentioned in [the documentation for `group(int)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28int%29):

> **Throws:**
>
> `IllegalStateException` - If no match has yet been attempted, or if the previous match operation failed

Comment: Doh.  Thank you so much for pointing that out Mark.  I learned a lot, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

`(new java.io.File("C:\workspace\photon\output\i686\diagnostic\photon.exe(Suspended) Thread(Running)")).getName().split("\\.")[0];`

Comment: Are you sure this will work? `(Suspended) Thread(Running)` is not a part of the file name

Comment: @Ron: It works fine.  From `File`'s point of view, it's just part of the last segment (the file name).  It's legal, but that doesn't mean it's a correct path or that the file exists.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex: `[\\d\\w]+\\.exe`

It assumes the executable only has digits and letters.

Another option is to use `.+\\.exe` to get the full file name and use `substring` and `lastIndexOf('\')` to get the file name.
You can also use `new File(fullFilePath).getFileName()` which is a more correct way to do it as it will save you the `substring` - but I don't know if it has better performance.